# How Do I Convert Ticks string to a DateTime in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, datetime

I got the tick count from a REG_QWORD in the registry. I then display the tick count & data type to verify I got what I expected:

```
ticks = 638254472943517809 (data type = ulong)
```

So far, so good. But when I try to convert it to a DateTime, I get this error message:

```
Write-Error: Cannot convert value "638254472943517809" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String '638254472943517809' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Here's my code. The commented out lines are various techniques I found on the Web, all of which fail with the same error:

```
     Write-Host "Ticks = $ticks (data type = $($ticks.getType()))"
#    $dateTime = [DateTime]$ticks
#    $dateTime = Get-Date -date $ticks
#    $dateTime = Get-Date [long]$ticks
```

PowerShell verified that the $ticks variable is a **ulong** as expected (see first output above). But when I try to convert it to a DateTime in the very next line, PowerShell says the $ticks variable is a **string**.

What am I doing wrong?

$PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: `[datetime]::new([long] '638254472943517809')` should work just fine

Comment: Well, it works, though I had to modify it because I can't hard code the tick value:
’’’
$dateTime = [datetime]::new([long] $ticks.ToString())
’’’
Also found this approach, which works, as well:
’’’
$dateTime = New-Object System.DateTime $ticks
’’’
What bothers me as much as anything is that after spending two hours Googling, I can't find any official Microsoft documentation on how to accomplish this.
Does anyone know where to find such docs?

Comment: Are you looking to understand why its failing when you cast `[datetime]` instead of using the constructor (`::new(..)`) ?

Comment: The error tells you the issue, the ticks is being retrieved/stored as a string in your variable. 
`Error: "String '638254472943517809' was not recognized as a valid DateTime` If you believe the variable is appropriate type, I'd assume you added quotes around $ticks in this attempt '[DateTime]"$ticks"` which would make it a string. If you're not doing that, then I'd say we are missing a piece of the puzzle and regardless you can force it like this just fine. `[DateTime][long]$ticks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give some clarity on why your examples are failing, when *casting* happens PowerShell attempts many different bindings to convert the source type into the target type, in your case, a [`ulong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64?view=net-7.0) into a [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0). The most commonly known binding attempts happen against the [type's constructor overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-7.0#overloads), its `Parse` method if the type has one defined and [explicit / implicit defined conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators), again, if the type has one defined, [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-7.0) if the type implements the interface and so on. See the [**Conversions doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06?view=powershell-7.3#614-conversion-to-other-reference-types) for more in depth details.

The error:

```
...Error: "String '638254472943517809' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Is telling us that PowerShell attempted a conversion using the [`[datetime]::Parse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0) which takes a `string` as input and, if successful, would produce a new instance of the `datetime` struct. So, what happens is that the `ulong` you had, was first coerced into a `string` thus the `String '638254472943517809'` in the error message.

With a bit of help you can tell PowerShell to target the [`long` ctor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-ctor(system-int64)) then it has no problems converting a `ulong` to a `long` and everything works great!

```bash
$ticks = [ulong] 638254472943517809
[datetime]::new($ticks)

Thursday, July 20, 2023 10:54:54 AM
```

The same would happen if you cast `long` before casting `datetime`:

```bash
[datetime] [long] [ulong] 638254472943517809

Thursday, July 20, 2023 10:54:54 AM
```

The `Get-Date` example is also correct, you're just missing the parentheses so the **conversion from `ulong` to `long` happens before the argument being passed to the cmdlet**:

```bash
Get-Date ([long] $ticks)
```

---

**NOTE:** The `[ulong]` type accelerator doesn't exist in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and prior, in these versions you would be using `[uint64]` instead or you can add the `[ulong]` accelerator to your current session via reflection:

```bash
[powershell].Assembly.
    GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Add('ulong', [UInt64])
```

Comment: Excellent answer, although I'd suggest using `[uint64]` in place of `[ulong]`, for backwards compatibility :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen woops you're right  thaks for the feedback